# Can Azure web app deployments slots be swapped via the REST API?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I want to swap my Azure web app staging and production slots via http, is there an api to do this? This is the Powershell cmdlet of what I want to do:

```
Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction -ResourceGroupName {my resource group} -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/slots -ResourceName {my resource name} -Action slotsswap -Parameters $ParametersObject -ApiVersion 2015-07-01
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, there's a REST API for swapping slots. You can find the REST API documentation here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps#WebApps_SwapSlotSlot

Comment: Thanks! I found this a few minutes ago, not easy to track down at all.